# Python's subprocessing with pipes and large files

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess

I'm trying to use python + ffmpeg + oggenc to convert any audiofile to ogg. The program works, almost. But for big files (i think > ~6mb) the ffmpeg process starts to sleep at pipe_wait. I don't know which pipe it waits for.

If I kill the ffmpeg process, the oggenc process continues and I get a resulting ogg-file with about ~2:40 of all the sound.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from sys import argv

ffmpeg = Popen([
    "ffmpeg",
    "-i", argv[1],
    "-vcodec", "null",
    "-acodec", "pcm_s16le",
    "-ac", "2",
    "-ab", "44100",
    "-f", "wav",
    "-"
],stdout = PIPE,stderr = PIPE)

oggenc = Popen([
    "oggenc",
    "-", "--raw",
    "-q", "4",
    "-o", argv[2]
],stdin = ffmpeg.stdout,stderr = PIPE)

oggenc.communicate()
ffmpeg.communicate()
```

EDIT:

Thought I might add that this works perfectly:

```
#!/bin/bash

ffmpeg -i "$1" -vcodec null -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 2 -ab 44100 -f wav - | oggenc - --raw -q 4 -o "$2"
```

Comment: Check my answer's update for your “>/dev/null” equivalent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What exactly do you do with the `stderr` channels of the two pipes?

Encoders/decoders typically produce lots of stderr output, as status updates; this output is piped to your process, and buffers will become full. Perhaps you should add some dummy `ffmpeg.stderr.read()` call before the (useless, I think) `.communicate` calls, or even better, drop the `stderr=PIPE` arguments completely.

### UPDATE

For the `>/dev/null` equivalent, do the following:

```
nulfp = open(os.devnull, "w")
…
… = subprocess.Popen(…, stderr=nulfp.fileno())
```

Obviously, you can re-use the same `nulfp` for all `stderr`s you want to ignore.

Comment: The reason I had stderr piped was becuase I didn't wanted it to write anything to the terminal. I tried using "-loglevel quiet" on ffmpeg to see if it worked, but than the everything just quited directly. First I thought it was the .communicate that terminated the program but as it turns out: It was ffmpeg not liking "-loglevel quiet" so it terminated itself.

Everything works when I drop the stderr=PIPE arguments, thanks for your help! Now I just need to figure out how to not show the sdterr data...

Comment: Just did the same thing but without .fileno(), any pros/cons using it?

Comment: It's the same, no pros/cons. The subprocess module will get the `.fileno()` internally when you give it a file object.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! For future reference: one still needs to do `null = open(os.devnull,'w')`.

Answer (score 0):

Its tricky to see who needs to pass the pipe,  eer I mean you should use a debugger like the one in NetBeans to help gather more clues.   Pipe's may not be the best approach,  perhaps using a temporary file would simplify things.

Comment: Well, temporary files was my first thought but then it will take almost twice the time, first ffmpeg converts the file to raw audio and then oggenc converts it to ogg/vorbis. With pipes they can do it at the same time, which saves time.

Comment: …and pipes will make better use of multiple cores (if available).